# Adding a callback when reading from an object in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Let's say I have a basic entity called `Entity` which is mapped to a database table. This entity has got two properties: `propertyA` and `propertyB`.

One particularity of this entity is, although we may store whatever we want in these properties, when using the value of `propertyB` on a Twig template with `entity.propertyB` we want to systematically truncate the value to 100 characters.

Now, this is perfectly doable in several ways:

- Truncate the value directly in the `getPropertyB()` method;
- Register a Twig extension and create a dedicated filter;
- Add a lifecycle callback on the entity to truncate the value before the object is actually created.

As this is strictly a display rule, and not a business rule on our entity, the second solution seems to be the best IMHO. However, it demands we apply the filter every time we need to use the value of `propertyB` in a template. Should an unaware developer come by, the value may not be truncated.

So my question is: is there a way to register some kind of callback, strictly restricted to the view model wrapping our entity, which would allow us to apply some filters on the fly on some of its properties ?

Comment: why not add a function in the `Entity` class of `getPropertyBView()` that returns a truncated string, you could also add a `getProportyAView()` that just returns the standard getter so new devs will only see the get view functions in the twig and will just copy what they see?

Comment: That could be an idea, but I see two drawbacks here:

First, it pollutes the model with code which is specific to the view side of things; Then it does not prevent other developers to use the original method.

Plus, to give you a bit of context, imagine this entity is currently used in multiple templates. That would require to manually change every call to `entity.propertyB` by `entity.propertyBView`.

Comment: In addition to your third options, you could have one property say `title` and another one `title_short`. The first one should be bound to database table field, and the value of other will be assigned on lifecycle callback. This, however, still requires for developer *to know* which to call :-/ And it still polutes your model as you described above...

Comment: Yes, that's actually the solution I've been using so far, but like you said it still raises some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you never need to access anything beyond 100 characters, you can truncate the property in its setter. This doesn't really pollute Entity code, because this is some logic inherent to it.

Comment: Actually it kinda does I guess. If I build my entity with a truncated string as a property, I might end up persisting it back to the database with the truncated version.